# How do I git pull at a specific date or time?

Tags: git, github

I want to run the command (git pull origin 02:00:00) or something like that and leave, and at that time my local repo grab the latest files from the remote repo automatically.

I am working with a coworker and he said he should have something for me to pull by a specific time (say 2 hours from now). I've seen searching and all I can find are guides/tutorials/tips on how to do a git checkout by date, or retrieve files of a certain date.

Is that even possible or would I need to physically type in the command in my terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run Git commands at some future time,
that's not a Git feature,
that's a scheduling task.
One tool you can use is the `at` command, for example:

```
at now + 2 hours
```

This will give you a prompt, typically `at>`, where you can type commands to run later, for example `git pull`.
After you typed all the commands you want to run, press `Control-D` to complete the `at` command.

Another solution is to sleep for two hours and then do `git pull`:

```
sleep 7200 && git pull
```

Yet another solution is to use `cron`.